# Move category description to bottom of page on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I really need help to move the category description to the bottom of the category page between the pagination and the footer?

I have absolutely no idea which file to look for...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to change the archive-product.php in

/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates

find this and paste it before the woocommerce_after_main_content_hook :

```
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>
```

just solved the same problem

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem:) I just don't understand why people down voted my question to -2.

Comment: dont worry @affiliater about people who voted -2. It will become +2 by the people who will get benefited by this question. I have already up vote to it :)

Answer (score 23):

add this to the theme functions.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 100 );
```

you can also change the layout by adding this function also and change the echo code.

```
function woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description() {
  if ( is_tax( array( 'product_cat', 'product_tag' ) ) && get_query_var( 'paged' ) == 0 ) {
    $description = wpautop( do_shortcode( term_description() ) );
    if ( $description ) {
      echo '<div class="term-description">' . $description . '</div>';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>
```

Markus G, In case of pagination 'woocommerce_archive_description' is not work for inner paginated pages.

Answer (score 0):

try `<?php echo category_description(); ?>` rather than `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>` and the 2nd code gives more than just the description.

You will also want to delete the description being outputted by your wootheme that noone except for backups seems to be addressing?